# Content type template takes precedence over specific node id template. How to change priority?

Tags: 9

In my `MYCUSTOMTHEME.theme` file, I've added page template suggestion for specific content types and paths, so that I can use `page--node--CONTENT-TYPE.html.twig` to override certain pages.

In MYCUSTOMTHEME.theme, I use:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter().
 */
function MYCUSTOMTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Add twig template name suggestions
  // For content types
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__node__' . $node->bundle();
  }
}
```

Now I've noticed that the general content type template takes priority over the specific node ID template:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x page--node--landing-page.html.twig
   * page--node--125549.html.twig
   * page--node--%.html.twig
   * page--node.html.twig
   * page.html.twig
-->
```

Is there any way to change this order?

Comment: Order of suggestions matters, don't append your own suggestion add the end of the suggestion array. The later in the array, the higher the priority of your suggestion.

Comment: As Hudri said, you need to reorder the array so that your suggestion is earlier in the array than the ID-specific suggestion. You didn't show the code you are using to add your suggestion, so we can't provide specifics on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The only thing I add in my .theme file is a suggestion for the content type (using the MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter function). My theme has Classy as the base theme, but that is not adding any template suggestions either as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've added the code I use in my .theme file to the post

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. [This comment](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2015-07-02/how-to-add-in-drupal-8-a-custom-suggestion-page-template#comment-10684366) on Drupal.org suggests using `array_splice()` to insert the template suggestion in the correct position.

The code in my .theme file is now:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter().
 */
function formule_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    array_splice($suggestions,1,0,'page__node__' . $node->bundle());
  }
}
```

This results in:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x page--node--126027.html.twig
   * page--node--%.html.twig
   * page--node--landing-page.html.twig
   * page--node.html.twig
   * page.html.twig
-->
```

Thanks again for the hints provided in the comments.